# Samsung A51 accidently flashed the wrong firmware, now doesnt even boot into dowload

Tags: samsung, device-firmware

I was trying to flash the official firmware again on my a51 but i accidently put the a20e on it, i was distracted, i have almost 30gb of different firmware downloaded and i chose the wrong one by distraction... i feel so stupid right now... this never happened to me before... what should i do? is there any way to fix it? even if i have to buy a new piece of hardware of storage or wtv piece i need to replace

Thank you in advance to whoever is able to help me

Comment: How did you flash wrong firmware? How did you by-pass CRC check?